# How to have a button and a combo box together

Tags: c#, button, uwp, combobox

I want to have a combo box with a button that looks like this:
[image]
As I want to use this so that items can be selected and added to a ListView.

**Issues:**

1. I don't know how to get and icon in the button like shown
2. How do you get them to line up really well or is there a way to combine the two elements that I am unaware of?

Comment: A `UserControl` would be the way to go. It's essentially a custom control where you can bundle controls together.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here's a working example.

Let's suppose your user control has two controls; a `ComboBox` and a `Button`. You want to be able to bind something from your main (parent) to the user control. Then upon selecting something and clicking the button, you want user control to notify to the parent of the event occurrence, and also pass the selected value.

The UserControl `XAML`:

```
<UserControl ...
             d:DesignHeight="40" d:DesignWidth="200">
    <Grid>
        <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
            <ColumnDefinition Width="160"/>
            <ColumnDefinition Width="40"/>
        </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>

        <ComboBox Grid.Column="0" Margin="4" Name="ItemsComboBox"
                  ItemsSource="{Binding Source, RelativeSource={RelativeSource AncestorType=UserControl}}"/>
        <Button Grid.Column="1" Margin="4" Content="+"
                Click="Button_Click"/>
    </Grid>
</UserControl>
```

The following binding will allow you to bind a list of data to the combo box, form the parent:

```
ItemsSource="{Binding Source, RelativeSource={RelativeSource AncestorType=UserControl}}"
```

From your `MainWindow`, you'll use the control like so:

```
<Grid>
    <local:UCComboButton Grid.Row="0" Width="200" Height="40" x:Name="MyUC"
                         Source="{Binding Names}"/>
</Grid>
```

And in the `UserControl`s code behind:

```
public partial class UCComboButton : UserControl
{
    public UCComboButton()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }

    // We use this dependency property to bind a list to the combo box.
    public static readonly DependencyProperty SourceProperty = DependencyProperty.Register("Source", typeof(IEnumerable), typeof(UCComboButton), new PropertyMetadata(null));

    public IEnumerable Source
    {
        get { return (IEnumerable)GetValue(SourceProperty); }
        set { SetValue(SourceProperty, value); }
    }

    // This is to send the occurred event, in this case button click, to the parent, along with the selected data.
    public class SelectedItemEventArgs : EventArgs
    {
        public string SelectedChoice { get; set; }
    }

    public event EventHandler<SelectedItemEventArgs> ItemHasBeenSelected;

    private void Button_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        var selected = ItemsComboBox.SelectedValue;
        ItemHasBeenSelected?.Invoke(this, new SelectedItemEventArgs { SelectedChoice = selected.ToString() });
    }
}
```

Now in the `MainWindow.xaml.cs`:

```
public MainWindow()
{
    InitializeComponent();
    // Subscribe to the item selected event
    MyUC.ItemHasBeenSelected += UCButtonClicked;

    Names = new List<string>
    {
        "A",
        "B",
        "C"
    };

    DataContext = this;
}

void UCButtonClicked(object sender, UCComboButton.SelectedItemEventArgs e)
{
    var value = e.SelectedChoice;
    // Do something with the value
}
```

Note that the above `Names` list is what's bound to the user control from the main window `XAML`.